Is there a safe way to create a Component or Directive that apply an encapsulated class to an input tag i.e. <input com-input>?
my goal is to use the input tag with selector[attribute] instead of selector to avoid wrapping the input with a host component.
I prefer selector[attribute] over selector] to avoid reinventing the wheel i.e. if I want to support autocomplete, I have to use @Input() autocomplete: string = "" and then add it to the <com-input autocomplete='email'>
Expected usage
    <input
      com-input
      #inputEmail
      autocomplete="username"
      (input)="email = inputEmail.nativeElement.value"
      [isError]="errorMessage ? true : false"
      placeholder="Email"
      type="email"
    />

The problem is:

when we add the attribute i.e. <input com-input> and then add a hash symbol i.e. <input com-input #inputElement>, the the inputElement type become InputComponent instead of HTMLInputElement. So, we can not access the input value.

The solution is:

implement ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> and inject ElementRef to InputComponent. Then, set the nativeElement property.

However, Angular documentation warned that the ElementRef is not safe. So, I am pretty sure my work is a hack.
/* eslint-disable @angular-eslint/component-selector */
import { Component, ElementRef, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'input[com-input]',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrl: './input.component.scss',
})
export class InputComponent implements ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> {
  nativeElement: HTMLInputElement;

  @HostBinding('class.error') @Input() isError: boolean = false;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.nativeElement = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
}



why not use (input)="email = $event"? NOTE: I try in Angular 17 and the reference variable inside the .html is the HTMLElement input. More over, I need use exportAs if I want to execute some method of the directive.

You could just use the read property of @ViewChild and just access the element ref from the parent directly
On the parent you can give
@ViewChild('inputEmail', { read: Element ref }) inputEmail: Element ref<any>;

On the html just give
 <input
  com-input
  #inputEmail
  autocomplete="username"
  (input)="email = inputEmail.nativeElement.value"
  [isError]="errorMessage ? true : false"
  placeholder="Email"
  type="email"
/>


I still need to inject ElementRef to the InputComponent.

@JasonRichDarmawan I am not sure if just accessing the native element is the problem, it might be inserting unsafe content inside the native element or even modifying the native Element, instead we need to do dom manipulation with renderer2

Ah I see. Anyway, I noticed that angular material use directive for matInput which when we call <input matInput #inputEmail/>, the inputElement will stay as HTMLInputElement. Do you happen to know how to add the style? I think I prefer this over having to access ElementRef

There are heavy limitation on styling Material components, I'd suggest taking a look at the official documentation : https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

@JasonRichDarmawan You can use renderer2, which has multiple methods like addClass or addStyle the first argument is the nativeelement and the second will be the class or style, the advantage of this is that, the content is sanitized so there won't be security issues, stackblitz demo not by me
